# Does any one have good and clear demo about Calabash(Android)?

Tags: automated-testing, calabash

I am learning Calabash My question:- does any one have good and clear demo about Calabash(Android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found good and clear demo for you, it works fine for me:

- https://github.com/bootstraponline/calabash_android_example

That example based on GitHub for android app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, with the usage of Page Object concept:

- https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TestCloud/TaskyPro/TaskyPro-Calabash

Look into `features` directory.